# Change vertical margins/size of the address fields in the koma-letter-export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, latex-header

I'm trying to export a letter as a pdf using `org-koma-letter-export-to-pdf` command, which is part of the [koma-letter-export](https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/koma-letter-export.html) package (ox-koma-letter.el).

By default `to` and `from` address fields take up half of the page at the top. Using Org headers is there any way to reduce them, for example to 25%?

I've tried adding:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setplength{\backaddrheight}{0cm}
```

or

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setplength{toaddrvpos}{1pt}
```

but it didn't work.

I was able to align them to the left by addding:

```
#+LCO: SNLeft
```

but I couldn't find any way to "squeeze" them vertically.

That would be really useful to have more space for the body of the letter.

Comment: I tried it with the [example letter](https://orgmode.org/worg/exporters/koma-letter-export.html#org9603a07) and I cannot reproduce the problem: the `To` and `From` take up about 20% of the page (even with the Montague coat of arms :-)). Can you post an example Org file where you see the problem?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this example letter, it's helped me a lot. The line, which rendered the heading 20% (as opposed to my 40%) is the `#+LCO: DINmtext`. However, it would be nice if one could override this value without loading the entire LCO?

Comment: The LCO files are supposed to accommodate the standard paper sizes and envelope constraints for a particular jurisdiction. I suspect the space that is left is exactly what's needed to put the fold in the right place so that the folder letter fits the envelope. If you don't care about that, then you probably need to write your own LCO file - but that's a `koma-script` question, not an Emacs one. See the table of LCO files available in Table 4.19, p.248 of the [Koma Script doc](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf).

Comment: Having said that, I would experiment with modifying the value of `tfoldmarkvpos` in the (default for the Org exporter) `NF.lco` file. In my case (Linux with TeXLive), this file is found at `:/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/NF.lco`; I would make a local copy to make modifications in, make a link to the local copy in the system directory and customize `org-koma-letter-class-option-file` to point to it (AFAICT, it's only the filename you can customize, not the directory where it's found - hence the linking rigmarole).

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I didn't realize that the header size may be preset to fit the envelope (haven't used physical letters in a while). I will leave it be then, but thank you for explaining the procedure for customizing the LCO files.

Comment: Yes, they are trying to accommodate standard envelopes with windows and those windows can be all different sizes and positions, so it is important to position the recipient's name and address so as to show through the window (and possibly the sender's name and address to show through a different window) and arrange everything else around that. As I said, you may choose not to worry about that at all, so just make up your own.